# Need help trying to attach a dictionary key and value to separate ListView GridViewColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, data-binding

XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="155" Height="Auto" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MedialDictionary}"></ListView>
```

C# ViewModel:

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> _medialDictionary;
public Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> MedialDictionary
{
    get => _medialDictionary;
    set => SetProperty(ref _medialDictionary, value);
}
```

- The dictionary key = `DateTime`
- The Dictionary value = `decimal`
- WPF looks like this:

  [image: ListView with multiple items like "[10/10/2008 00:00:00, 500]".]

---

I want to have the key in one column of the list and a value in the other. I have added `GridView` columns inside the `ListView`, but do not how to bind the properties correctly (EffectiveDate, Value).
I have read much documentation, however it has not made any sense to me so I am looking for advice/solutions here.

Comment: USING @thatguy's answer and implementing </ListView.View> the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item in a [`Dictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) is a [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-6.0), which is a `struct` with a [`Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.key?view=net-6.0) and a [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.value?view=net-6.0) property that you can bind.

In order to display a tabular layout with columns, you can use a [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Each colum has a [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property that the corresponding property to display is bound to.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="155" Height="Auto" Margin="10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MedialDictionary}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Date"
                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Value"
                         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @HyperSquid You most likely bind `ItemsSource` and at the same time add items to `ListView`. You can only use one of both.